# What chapters are in the Shulchan aruch haRav for Yoreh Deah?

Tags: chabad, shulchan-aruch, yoreh-deah

I currently own the Weiss edition S.A haRav (not the all Hebrew one), and I think YD is almost done being translated and published by Kehot. Does anyone know what chapters the Weiss edition Yoreh Deah of the Alter Rebbe's S.A has? Like I said I don't have the all Hebrew edition and so I don't know what's going to be in the billingual Weiss edition.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Niel and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here are the contents:](https://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/index.htm)

Hilchos Shechitah: sections 1-2, 18, 23-26

Hilchos Treifos: sections 30-33

Hilchos Ribbis/Iska: a digest (similar in style to the Choshen Mishpat volume by the same author, vol. 12 of Weiss), corresponding to sections 160-177

Hilchos Niddah: sections 183-191

Laws of Constructing a Mikvah: a practical guide (similar in style to Seder Hachnosas Shabbos by the same author), based on parts of sections 198 and 201

Hilchos Talmud Torah: a digest, corresponding to sections 242-246

Shechitah, Treifos and Niddah are structured as glosses on the Mechaber's Shulchan Aruch, some simply explanatory, others digressive and similar in style to Kuntres Acharon on the other sections. In the existing Weiss volumes they didn't translate the Kuntres Acharon word for word, just summarized each one; whether they plan to do that for these sections in Yoreh De'ah, I don't know.